# PHP if ($_POST) annoyance

Tags: php, post

I find myself working through a lot of other peoples' code nowadays. I noticed `if (isset($_POST))` in some of the code and made sure to fix that. (It will always evaluate `true`). Then I start seeing this:

```
if ($_POST)
```

After thinking through this, it annoys me, but still seems to work. Does anyone see any issues with using this to check if a form has been submitted? If the `$_POST` array is empty, then it evaluates as `false`. Any special cases where this might not work?

Comment: Btw why do you check for POST array ? You will be checking for POST variables right ? `$_POST["data1"]`

Comment: it's probably better to check individual `POST` variables for validity but a good reason for using it is incase a user navigates to your form-processing page manually, in this case the `POST` array will be empty and you can deal with the situation accordingly. I don't think there is a situation where that bit of code will fail though. I think the best bet is to use that, and then check each variable individually inside the `if`.

Comment: I always check for specific values. I'm just wondering if I should go through and edit hundreds of instances of if ($_POST) found in other peoples code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an unreliable test - it assumes that at least one form element will be submitted. It's entirely possible to perform a POST where no data is submitted, which would make `if ($_POST)` evaluate to false, but be meta-false as a POST was actually performed.

The proper 100% reliable test is

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

To check if an array is empty you should use [`count()`](http://php.net/count) or [`sizeof()`](http://php.net/sizeof) and check if it is greater than zero:

```
if( count($_POST) > 0 )
{ # Array not empty
}
```

---

A better way to check if a form is submitted is to check if there are post vars sent:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{ # Form submitted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no cases where it won't (not that I can think of, anyway), but I would still do:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
```

to make it clearer exactly what you are doing. This is effectively the same statement, but makes it more obvious.

Comment: empty is not correct. If array(0) it is also empty. Use [`count`](http://php.net/count) to check the size.

Comment: @WouterJ `If array(0) it is also empty` - not true. Try this `$arr = array(0); var_dump(empty($arr));`

Comment: @DaveRandom, try this: if (empty(array(0))) echo "I'm empty";

Comment: That is because `empty()` (effectively) takes it's input by reference. If you pass a value that has not been assigned to a variable it will be empty, because you effectively didn't pass anything. Turn or error reporting, you will see what I mean...

Answer (score 1):

Before PHP 4.1 there was no $_POST. Instead there was a variable called $HTTP_POST_VARS which did the same except that it was not a superglobal. $HTTP_POST_VARS is deprecated and hopefully you don't need to worry about this too much, but the check for $_POST may actually return false if you run a php < 4.1 installation, so your code might have checked for that.

`if ($_POST)` behaves identical to `if (!empty($_POST))` except for one important difference: The first version will throw a Notice if $_POST is not set, the empty()-version will not throw a notice (of course error_output must be set to echo notices for you to see something). You should always use empty if the variable you are checking might be not set.

I'd say that if you find an `if ($_POST)` than that's a bad smell. You already notice that the intention of the original coder is unclear. If he want's to know that an HTTP-Request used the POST-method, then Wouter's answer makes the intention much clearer. If he wanted to check whether the $_POST exists at all (check for old PHP version), then `isset($_POST)` is clearer. If he wanted to check that a POST-request has at least one parameter send using POST, then `empty($_POST)` is much clearer, also such an intention should be extremely seldom.

My advise is to continue reading the source and check if you can figure out which intention the original coder had and then replace the construct accordingly (or at least put a comment on that line).

Comment: That makes a little more sense, since I'm working with prehistoric code.

Answer (score 0):

```
[timwolla@/var/www]telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /test.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 13
Connection: close

array(0) {
}
```

Seems to be fine with GET-Requests as well. But it is much more readable to use `!empty($_POST)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when the form the programmer did not expect POSTed, it becomes a very dangerous test.  My pattern is to test for each field I expect:

```
if (isset($_POST['foo_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['foo_id'])
    && isset($_POST['name'])
    && isset($_POST['value'])
) {
```

In this way I can be sure there is no chance of processing the wrong form.